# Return ManyRelatedManager values in template

Tags: python, django

I'm new to programming so i'm sure there's an obvious simple solution to this.
I have two models (in separate apps):

```
class Order(models.Model):
  parts = models.ManyToManyField(Part, blank=True)

class Part(models.Model):
  mwos = models.ManyToManyField('mtn.Order', blank=True)
```

The problem is when i render `Order` in `DetailView` in template i can't get the queryset of associated values. If i just put `{{ order.parts }}` i get `my_app.Part.None`.

And if i do this

```
class OrderDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Order

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['parts'] = Part.objects.filter(mwos=self.object.id)
        return context
```

I get `{{ parts }}` rendered as empty queryset `<QuerySet []>`.

UPDATE:

Turns out all i needed was add `.all` to `{{ order.parts.all }}`

Comment: You render it with `{{ order.parts.all }}`. This will render `<QuerySet []>`. You need to *iterate* over it, but right now, it looks like your `Order` does not have any `parts`.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what i needed.

Comment: why do you have m2m defined in both models? You should have only one of them and remove the other. Lets say you remove the `mwos` field in `Part`, then you can still access the orders with `part.order_set.all`. What you have now are two different relationships, if you add a `Part` object to `parts` it has nothing to do with your `mwos` relationship in `Order`. Django actually created two different m2m tables to keep track of the relationships.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks